# What to do with GL_INVALID_OPERATION on glGenVertexArrays?

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl

When trying to set up an OpenGL context within a custom NSOpenGLView, any call to `glGenVertexArrays` does not seem to write the output and it raises `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.  The [docs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGenVertexArrays.xhtml) say that `glGenVertexArrays` could only indicate `GL_INVALID_VALUE`, and not `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` as it is the case.  Also, in the same code, `glGenBuffers` works as expected.

```
// within NSOpenGLView.prepareOpenGL:
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
// glGetError() == 0

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
// glGetError() == GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

So, how do I generate Vertex Arrays properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the framework thought that I wanted to use the legacy profile.

What did solve my issue is specifying a Pixel Format in the view constructor:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    let attributes = [
        UInt32(NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer),
        UInt32(NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile), UInt32(NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core),
        0
    ]
    let pixelFormat = NSOpenGLPixelFormat(attributes: attributes)

    super.init(coder: coder)

    self.pixelFormat = pixelFormat
}
```